# Цикличный запрос внутри flatMap rxJava

Tags: java, android, rxjava

Как можно реализовать цикличный подзапрос в Rx? Подробнее описал внизу..

```
private Observable<List<Integer>> sendData(){//какой то код};
private Observable<Boolean> sendInfoData(int id){//какой то код};   

sendData()
.flatMap(data->{ //data = List каких то id
    //необходимо что то типа цикла
    for(int id : data){
        sendInfoData(id);
        //и после успешного выполнения всех запросов sendInfoData идти дальше по цепочке вниз.. 
    }

})
.subscribe(data -> {
   getViewState().showSubmitSuccessView();
}, getErrorHandler()::procced);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вроде бы как-то так должно быть:

```
sendData()
    .flatMap( items -> Observable.fromIterable(items))
    .flatMap( item -> sendInfoData(item))
    .toList()
    .subscribe(listOfBooleans -> {});
```